# Scaling issue in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game scene for Unity. However, I can't seem to get rid of this border. Or I can't seem to stretch my background to fit the whole screen. I need this scaling to work for all screen sizes. Here is an image of what is happening.

[image]

You can clearly see the blue edging, when I don't want that to be happening. This happens when I test on my Tablet as well. The camera is of size 5, however, when I do some debugging, I notice it gives me positions such as 7.15 when I touch on the screen. How can I scale everything down, I have searched through tons of forums and no one seems to be having this issue.

Comment: I really don't understand your problem here. Can you circle where you see the blue edge? Zoom out and take screenshot again. Also, is your background a sprite under the Canvas UI or just a normal 2D Sprite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using UI panel for the background? if so try these step.

1st strech the background Panel to fit the whole canvas size

[image]

then change the background panel to stretch in all directions

[image]

Then select the canvas object and render mode for screen space camera, assign your camera to it and change the UI scale mode to  'scale with Screen size'

[image]

Comment: Excellent, I really appreciate all the effort. Thank you!