# What I should to use to create 2d fix background

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've found many diferentes ways to set fixed background in unity3d, but what is the best way, in performance to create and mobile app., just adding image , creating a plane with texture, assign texture to scene, using canvas

Comment: its probably irrelevant in the end, the question sounds a lot like premature optimization. if you really need to know, race your horses https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 1):

Using a UI canvas might be the best way, doing so you can manage the scaling, when application is loaded in different scaled screens. for scaling issue check 
[Scaling issue in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245641/scaling-issue-in-unity/37245756#37245756)